# Matlab and addpath

Tags: matlab

I have recently been working with Matlab. My question stems from my usage over a few months and is something that I can't seem to solve. I have an external SVM toolbox (OSU-SVM) that I would like to interface to with my project. I am able to get the entire system to work when I add the path of the toolbox manually (Right click ->  Add to Path -> Selected Folders and Subfolders). What I would like to do is add the folder in a script. I've tried the "addpath" command but for some reason I can't get it to find the library relative to the m-file (script) that I run the command from. The following is an example of the code:

```
% Add OSU SVM system
addpath(genpath('./osu-svm/'));
```

The reason the I'd like to add the path using a relative folder to the M-file is that the code needs to run in a different environment that will not have the toolbox install. The code is also going to be executed in a different OS to the one I am developing on. That is, I am running a Windows Matlab to develop the code and need to run the finished system on a Linux machine. The process of running my files needs to be as painless as possible and shouldn't require much input from the user. That is why I'm specifically trying to avoid manual addition of the path.

On a side note a similar problem occurs when I wish to use "uigetfile" using a relative path. I believe there is something I am missing that will help me solve both of these simultaneously. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of './osu-svm/' alone use

```
fullfile('.','osu-svm')
```

The reason it does not work for you on windows is that you are using forward slash file separators. Full file will make a file string containing the correct file separator for each OS.

The genpath example in the matlab documentation also uses fullfile
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/genpath.html

Furthermore, the '.' is kinda unnecessary as it just means "relative to the current directory" and can be left out of the command. Perhaps you meant one directory up?

```
'..'
```

???

Comment: Thanks this worked. I'm used to using "." to make it explicitly clear that the current folder is being used.